# Kotlin Flows, executing code when there are no active subscribers

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow, kotlin-stateflow

I have created a location repository that is responsible for collecting location data and transmitting it to whoever listens, the code right now looks something like this:

```
@Singleton
class LocationRepository @Inject constructor(
    app: Application
) {

    private val _location = MutableStateFlow<Location?>(null)
    private val subscribers = AtomicInteger()
    val location: Flow<Location?> = _location.onSubscription {
        if (subscribers.getAndIncrement() == 0)
            startUpdates()
    }.onCompletion {
        if (subscribers.decrementAndGet() == 0)
            stopUpdates()
    }

    private val client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(app)
    private val locCb = object : LocationCallback() {
        override fun onLocationResult(var1: LocationResult?) {
            newLocationResult(var1)
        }
        override fun onLocationAvailability(var1: LocationAvailability) {}
    }
    private val request = LocationRequest.create()

    init {
        request.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY
        request.interval = 5000L
        request.fastestInterval = 2500L
    }


    private fun startUpdates() { //code to start getting location updates }
    private fun stopUpdates() { //code to stop getting location updates }

}
```

right now I am handling the current number of subscribers with an `AtomicInteger`, is there a way to run the `startUpdates` code and the `stopUpdates` code automatically when the first subscriber subscribes and the last subscriber unsubscribes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check [`subscriptionCount`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-mutable-shared-flow/subscription-count.html) property of `MutableSharedFlow`, it may be what you are looking for. It has type of `StateFlow<Int>` and emits the number of subscribers (active collectors) to this shared flow. Example:

```
_location.subscriptionCount
    .map { count -> count > 0 } // map count into active/inactive flag
    .distinctUntilChanged() // only react to true<->false changes
    .onEach { isActive -> // configure an action
        if (isActive) startUpdates() else stopUpdates()
    }
    .launchIn(scope) // launch it
```

Comment: that would work, the problem is that I have created the repository as a singleton, which is used by many fragments throughout the application, what scope should I launch it in? Globalscope is considered a bad practice, and defining an application scope would mean that I can't cancel it

Comment: I would maybe made the repository a simple class (not a singleton) created a `CoroutineScope` property and cancel method in the repository. Or would moved logic to `ViewModel`. Or If you prefer to leave the repository  as Singleton, you can create a `CoroutineScope` property in it and use it, you will not cancel it, so it will have app life time.

Comment: but if I make it a simple class, and let's say fragments a b and c use it, and a opens b which opens c, three instances of the class will be created, with the code running three times, with only the active fragment actually showing results, since viewmodelscope of a and b are not cancelled since close hasn't been called

Comment: In this case you can share a `ViewModel` between fragments https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing

Comment: you're right, since it is a common resource it makes sense that I hook it up to the main activity's view model, didn't think of that